# NameError Python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, self

Estou estudando Python a algum tempo e estou com dúvida no código que fiz abaixo. Ao executá-lo está aparecendo o erro:

> "NameError: name 'p1' is not defined"

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
class Produto:


def __init__(self, nome, descricao, valor, senha):
    self.__nome = nome
    self.__descricao = descricao
    self.__valor = valor
    self.__senha = senha
    self.__mostrar_produto()

def __mostrar_produto(self):
    print(f'ID do produto: {p1.__id}')
    print(f'Nome do produto: {p1.__nome}')
    print(f'Descrição do produto: {p1.__descricao}')
    print(f'Valor do produto: {p1.__valor}')
    print(f'Senha: {p1.__senha}')


p1 = Produto('Computador', 'Gamer', 4000, '123456')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar a instância da classe dentro de um método dela. Mas o nome `p1` foi dado a uma instância fora da definição da classe. Nesse caso você deve chamar a própria instância com a palavra-chave `self`:

```
def __mostrar_produto(self):
    print(f'ID do produto: {self.__id}')
    print(f'Nome do produto: {self.__nome}')
    print(f'Descrição do produto: {self.__descricao}')
    print(f'Valor do produto: {self.__valor}')
    print(f'Senha: {self.__senha}')
```

E note, também, que sua classe `Produto` não tem um campo `__id`. Você pode defini-lo na classe:

```
def __init__(self, produto_id, nome, descricao, valor, senha):
    self.__id = produto_id
    self.__nome = nome
    self.__descricao = descricao
    self.__valor = valor
    self.__senha = senha
    self.__mostrar_produto()
```

Ao final, o código ficaria algo como:

```
class Produto:


    def __init__(self, produto_id, nome, descricao, valor, senha):
        self.__id = produto_id
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__descricao = descricao
        self.__valor = valor
        self.__senha = senha
        self.__mostrar_produto()
    
    def __mostrar_produto(self):
        print(f'ID do produto: {self.__id}')
        print(f'Nome do produto: {self.__nome}')
        print(f'Descrição do produto: {self.__descricao}')
        print(f'Valor do produto: {self.__valor}')
        print(f'Senha: {self.__senha}')


p1 = Produto(1, 'Computador', 'Gamer', 4000, '123456')
```

Se o executarmos teremos a seguinte saída:

```
ID do produto: 1
Nome do produto: Computador
Descrição do produto: Gamer
Valor do produto: 4000
Senha: 123456
```